# Running queries on two databases

Tags: php, mysql

Let say I am building a bookstore for all the books in a library.  People won't be buying these books, only renting them for so long.

They will have to create an account and the proceed to make a rental.  What I want to know is, what would stop some random person from a different city let say, making an account and renting all the books at once?(like a hack or a prank) I have come up with one solution where as to make the users only allowed to rent out one book per a certain time period, but then someone will could just make 100+ accounts if they so wish.

Could you only allow people to create an account who matches a certain criteria in another database(say user database) with there name, email and usernames? So that no one can just randomly make an account, only people who are already in a different database?

Comment: What solutions have you considered so far, and what problems did you find with them?

Comment: why not different table? what made you think a different database as such? or you are calling a table as a database??

Comment: I'm not working on this project (at least not yet) so I haven't experimented with anything.

Comment: And I guess a table would work too.  I guess I was thinking just fr organization

Comment: Keeping track of emails only will not do, as per your scenario, a malicious user can easily create multiple email accounts. Keep track of IP addresses as well, and only allow 1 registration per IP for a specific period or something.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you just can't avoid other people create many account, but you can limit some things.

**For example**

1- Check the user IP address. 
2- Avoid one person can rent more than one book. 
3- When you rent a book, you can get a DNI or some document that is unique.

Those, just are some examples, but how i told you, you can't control it.